# What bounds can we place on approximation error for a moment-matching approximation with $N$ moments?

Tags: distributions, moments, approximation, bounds

Suppose I have a distribution over the real line ($p$) and I'm approximating it by matching its first $N$ moments.  What can I say about the approximation error as a function of $N$?

Alternatively, how "pathological" does $p$ need to get for moment matching to produce a bad approximation? Would $p$ need to extremely narrow peaks and/or interspersed regions with approximately zero density, or can the approximation still be arbitrarily bad with a more "well-behaved" distribution?

Comment: Exactly what are you approximating the distribution with and how do you want to measure the approximation error?  (Matching $N$ moments rarely produces a unique distribution.)

Comment: Indeed even if you match moments of every order you may not get a unique distribution. Moments don't pin down distributions very well. Actually, there's a reference relating to your question.... hold on... yep here it is -- Bruce Lindsay and Prasanta Basak, (2000), "Moments determine the tail of a distribution (but not much else)”, *The American Statistician*, Vol 54, No 4, p. 248–251. (If you search for it you might even find a link to a pdf of that paper)

Comment: Thanks both. @Glen_b: at first glance, that paper looks like it could be very helpful. Much appreciated